# Diophantine equation $x^2 + y^2 = z^3$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have found all solutions to the Diophantine equation $x^2 + y^2 = z^3$ when 
$z$ is odd. I am having some difficulty finding the solutions when $z$ is even. I am asking for a proof that provides the solutions where $z$ is even. I want the proof to be elementary and use only Number theory and perhaps Calculus or basic ideas about groups and rings.

Comment: I see $x = y = z = 2$ is a trivial solution to the system.

Comment: If $z$ is even, then $x^2 + y^2$ is divisible by $4.$ In turn, this means both $x,y$ are even, with $x \equiv y \pmod 4.$ With enough effort this should allow you to finish.

Comment: @WillJagy: $x\equiv y\pmod 4$?

Comment: @GregMartin, calculate mod 8.

Comment: @GregMartin , yes, he has $z^3$ so we need $x^2 + y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 8.$ This means both are even. If, however, $x \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ but $y \equiv 0 \pmod 4,$ then $x^2 + y^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 8.$ In the earlier comment, I can see I did not mention $\pmod 8$

Comment: If $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$, then $(x,y,z)=\left(s\left(s^2-3t^2\right),t\left(3s^2-t^2\right),s^2+t^2\right)$ for coprime $s,t$ of opposite parity. See [here](http://www.few.vu.nl/~sdn249/BeChDaYa-misc.pdf) (page $11$).

Comment: If $(x,y,z)$ is a solution to $x^2+y^2=z^3$, then so is $$(8n^3x, 8n^3y, 4n^2z)$$ for any non-negative integer $n$. This relies on the fact that multiplying both sides of the equation by an even sixth power will yield another solution. This gives you an infinite number of even solutions for each solution that you find (you said you'd already found all the solutions with odd $z$). This probably doesn't yield all solutions with even $z$, but it may help.

Comment: @Zubin Mukerjee, I am already aware of this. I was wondering if there were some class of primitive solutions from which all solutions could be generated from like for Pythagorean triples

Comment: @Zubin Mukerjee Let a,b be integers. Then $(a^3 - 3ab^2,3a^2b - b^3, a^2 + b^2) is a solution. These solutions contain all the odd solutions

Comment: @TannerCarawan Interesting! How did you figure that out? It turns out my modulo $8$ thing only showed that there are no solutions with $x$, $y$ and $z$ all odd, which makes sense given your answer.

Comment: @WillJagy Could you explain why you think that's enough to finish

Comment: @Zubin Mukerjee x^2 + y^2 can only be congruent to 0,1, or 2 modulo 4 based on what the quadratic residues of 4 are. Based on the "cubic" residues of 4, z^3 could be congruent to 0,1, or 3. It is clear than that either z^3 is congruent to 1 modulo 4 or  0 modulo 4. Suppose z^3 is congruent to 1 modulo 4. It follows then that z is congruent to 1 mod 4. This implies that primes congruent to 3 mod 4 occur in the prime factorization of z an even number of times so that z is a sum of squares. Then z = a^2 + b^2 for some a and b. Hence, z = (a + ib)(a - ib).

Comment: @Zubin Mukerjee Thus x^2 + y^2 = (x + iy)(x-iy) = (a+ib)^3(a-ib)^3. Either x + iy = (a + ib)^3 or x + iy = (a - ib)^3 >Both give the same result. x + iy = a^3 + 3a^2bi - 3ab^2 - b^3i. Thus x = a^3 - 3b^2, y = 3a^2b - b^3, z = a^2 + b^2. Direct calculation reveal that this will be a solution for all a and b

Comment: [All coprime solutions below $10^4$](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rO9ZA.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't ([apparently](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562228/)) one complete ***polynomial*** parameterization to

$$x^2+y^2 = z^k\tag1$$

***when $k>2$***. For $k=2$, the complete solution is,

$$x,\,y,\,z = (a^2-b^2)s,\; (2ab)s,\; (a^2+b^2)s$$

where $s$ is a *scaling factor*. Using complex numbers $a+b i$, one can generalize the method. For $k=3$, it is

$$x,\,y,\,z = (a^3 - 3a b^2)s^3,\; (3a^2 b - b^3)s^3,\; (a^2+b^2)s^2\tag2$$

*but you can no longer find rational $a,b,s$ for certain solutions.* For example,

$\hskip2.7in$ $9^2+46^2 = 13^3\quad$ [Yes](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%5BResultant%5B%28a%5E3%20-%203a%20b%5E2%29s%5E3%20-%209%2C%20%283a%5E2b%20-%20b%5E3%29s%5E3%20-%2046%2C%20b%5D%5D)

$\hskip2.7in$ $58^2+145^2=29^3\quad$ [No](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%5BResultant%5B%28a%5E3%20-%203a%20b%5E2%29s%5E3%20-%2058%2C%20%283a%5E2b%20-%20b%5E3%29s%5E3%20-%20145%2C%20b%5D%5D)

(You can click on the *Yes/No* links for Walpha output.) A related discussion can be found in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383601/) while an alternative method is described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1386201/4781). For the case $k=3$, if $a^2+b^2=c^3$, then an infinite more can be found as,

$$(a u^3 + 3 b u^2 v - 3 a u v^2 - b v^3)^2 + (b u^3 - 3 a u^2 v - 3 b u v^2 + 
        a v^3)^2 = c^3(u^2+v^2)^3\tag3$$

which should provide some solutions not covered by $(2)$.

Comment: Is this a joke?  $$58^2+145^2=29^3$$ $$(2*29)^2+(5*29)^2=29^3$$ $$2^2+5^2=29$$  So can any nonlinear equation is reduced to linear.

Comment: @individ: Sigh... It should not take you a few seconds to answer your own question.

Comment: @Tanner Carawan: I asked a more general version of your question. Kindly see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562228/).

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: I looked at it. Thanks for answering my question. I have not yet studied enough Abstract Algebra to understand why there isn't a complete polynomial parametrization.

Answer (score 1):

[Fermat's two squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) says exactly which integers $n$ can be written as the sum of two squares, and indeed it can be made constructive, with a procedure to find all such representations. I recommend applying that known procedure to $n=z^3$. I don't think there's a significantly easier way; for example, already when $z$ is a high power of $5$ (or twice a high power of $5$), there are many representations.

Answer (score 0):

Playing with the degrees and undetermined coefficients, we try to solve
$$r^2(\alpha r^2+\beta s^2)^2+s^2(\gamma\space r^2+\delta s^2)^2=(\lambda r^2+\mu s^2)^3$$ in order to get an identity like for the pythagorean triples.

Operating, $$\alpha^2 r^6+(2\alpha \beta+\gamma^2)r^4s^2+(\beta^2+2\gamma \delta)r^2s^4+\delta^2 s^6=(\lambda r^2+\mu s^2)^3$$

We see convenient at first sight take $\alpha^2=\delta^2=1$ so that $$\pm2\beta+\gamma^2=\beta^2\pm2\gamma=3$$ 
Finally we take the values $$(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,\lambda,\mu)=(1, -3, 3,-1, 1, 1)$$ an we have get the identity
$$ [r(r^2-3s^2)]^2+[s(3r^2-s^2)]^2=(r^2+s^2)^3$$
From which infinitely many solutions.

Comment: All this is good, but the equations do not solve.  In the first formula, You actually set what type must have solutions.  But the equation we haven't decided about this kind of know nothing. Then solve the equation - when we do not know the solution.

Comment: Do you want to explain me more, please. I don´t understand what you desire to tell me. And consider I have no pretended to have found all the solutions but infinitely many of them by an identity which It was not sure I could get (have in account, please, my English of Google translator is weak)

Answer (score 0):

from equation: $\left( {p}^{2}+{k}^{2}\right) \,{z}^{2}={y}^{2}+{x}^{2}$

$(-2\,a\,b\,p-{b}^{2}\,k+{a}^{2}\,k,\left( {a}^{2}-{b}^{2}\right) \,p+2\,a\,b\,k,{b}^{2}+{a}^{2})$
$(2\,a\,b\,p-{b}^{2}\,k+{a}^{2}\,k,\left( {a}^{2}-{b}^{2}\right) \,p-2\,a\,b\,k,{b}^{2}+{a}^{2})$

if $z={p}^{2}+{k}^{2}$

${\left( {p}^{3}+{k}^{2}\,p\right) }^{2}+{\left( k\,{p}^{2}+{k}^{3}\right) }^{2}={\left( {p}^{2}+{k}^{2}\right) }^{3}$

${\left( {p}^{3}-3\,{k}^{2}\,p\right) }^{2}+{\left( 3\,k\,{p}^{2}-{k}^{3}\right) }^{2}={\left( {p}^{2}+{k}^{2}\right) }^{3}$

Comment: You lead the same solutions as above.  What's the point of this response?

Answer (score -1):

Usually a view.  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1124891_almost_pythagoras
http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1049554__

You can write the solution in this form.  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1054060_cubes_with_squares

http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048815___
http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1047876____

But usually use the standard simple approach. In the equation.

$$X^2+Y^2=Z^3$$

$$X=ab+cd$$

$$Y=cb-ad$$

And receive such record.

$$(a^2+c^2)(b^2+d^2)=Z*Z^2$$

$$b^2+d^2=Z^2$$

$$Z=a^2+c^2$$

So.

$$d=a^2-c^2$$

$$b=2ac$$

Then the decision on the record.

$$X=3ca^2-c^3$$

$$Y=3ac^2-a^3$$

$$Z=a^2+c^2$$

Comment: Is every solution of that form? Why can we say X = ab + cd and Y = cb - ad? Why must b^2 + d^2 = z^2 or z = a^2 + c^2? What is all this talk about "record"?

Comment: @TannerCarawan  Because such a simple entry - allows you to simply solve an equation.  So why not use it?