# On the integer solutions to $u^2+163v^2=w^3$ and others

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms, class-field-theory

It seems the solution of,

$$u^2+dv^2 = w^3\tag1$$

involves the *[class number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClassNumber.html)* $h(d)$. Assume $\gcd(u,v)=1$.

***Q***: For which $\color{red}{prime}\; d$ is the complete solution of $(1)$ in the integers given by,

$$(p^3 - 3 d p q^2)^2 + d(3 p^2 q - d q^3)^2 = (p^2+dq^2)^3\tag2$$

Equating terms between $(1)$ and $(2)$ and eliminating $q$, then the question is equivalent to solving,

$$u + 3 w p - 4 p^3 = 0\tag3$$

Using *Mathematica* to test various $d$, it seems it depends $\text{mod}\, 8$ and on the *class number* $h(d)$,

1. If $d=8n+1,8n+5$ with $h(4d)\neq3m$, then $(2)$ is complete with integer $p,q$. Ex. $d=5$.
2. If $d=8n+1,8n+5$ with $h(4d)=3m$, then $(2)$ is ***not*** complete. Ex. $d=29$.
3. If $d=8n+3$, then $(2)$ is complete with integer and [half-integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-integer) $p,q$. Ex. $d=11,163$.
4. If $d=8n+7$, then $(2)$ is ***not*** complete. Ex. $d=7,23$.

**Q:** Is $\text{#}1,2,3,4$ true?

Comment: I see you deleted $d=11.$ I'm not sure yet what you meant by half integers, but the thing does work out for $u^2 + uv + 3 v^2 = z^3.$

Comment: The argument is the 1923 paper of Dickson that Kieran asked me about in his recent question. That material is repeated in his 1929 book, Introduction to the Theory of Numbers, pages 91-96 mostly. I see how he has an exercise on page 96, solve $x^2 + y^2 = uvw$ which is your item above when $u=v=w$

Comment: @WillJagy: I only deleted some $d$ to unclutter the post. I'll restore $d=11$. By "half-integer", I mean that for any co-prime $u,v$, then one can ***always*** find $p,q = \frac{p'}{2}, \frac{q'}{2}$.

Comment: @WillJagy: For example, given $4^2+11*1^2 = 3^3$, then the only solution is $p,q =\pm\frac{1}{2},\pm\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Oh, alright. Actually, given any $w = x^2 + xy + 3 y^2,$ we can solve $u^2 + 11 v^2 = 4 w$ in integers.

Comment: @WillJagy: Equivalently, $\big(\frac{u}{2})^2+11\big(\frac{v}{2})^2=x^2+xy+3y^2$. Hence the half-integers on the LHS.

Comment: @WillJagy: I guess this also means $\big(\frac{u}{2})^2+163\big(\frac{v}{2})^2=x^2+xy+41y^2$ is solvable in the integers, right?

Comment: Yes, the 41 version is good.

Comment: this is not really surprising since elements of order $3$ in the class group correspond to solutions out of that parametrization. I guess when you take the wrong ring of integers, some weird stuff happens that either give trivial counterexamples or on the contrary make counterexamples have both even coordinates so that you don't consider them.